# Ajax data not getting into controller

Tags: ajax, laravel

I am using an ajax request to show some information, on my local development version it works perfectly, but on the production server (Ubuntu 16.04 LEMP) it fails in validation, because there is no data in the request.

**Checks**

- The url is correctly showing (e.g. example.com/employeeInfo?employeeId=1)
- Ajax itself is working: when I hard-code the controller's response everything is fine.

I cannot figure out why this happens in production, but not on the local version... Huge thanks for any clues!

## View

```
<script>
(function ($) {
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".team-pic").off("click").on("click", function() {

        var employeeId = $(this).data('id');

        // Get data
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "employeeInfo",
            data: {employeeId:employeeId},
            success: function(data){
                var obj=$.parseJSON(data);
                $('#team-info-title').html(obj.output_name);
                $('#team-info-subtitle').html(obj.output_role);
                $('#resume').html(obj.output_resume);
                $('#linkedin').html(obj.output_linkedin);
                $("#team-info-background").show();
                $("#team-info").show();
            }
        });

    });
});
}(jQuery));
</script>
```

## Route

```
Route::get('/employeeInfo', 'EmployeeController@getInfo');
```

## Controller

```
public function getInfo(Request $request) {

    if($request->ajax()) {

        $this->validate($request, [
            'employeeId' => 'required|integer',
        ]);

        $employee = Employee::find($request->employeeId);
        $output_linkedin = '<a href="'.$employee->linkedIn.'"class="linkedin" target="blank"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a>';

        $data = array("output_resume"=>$employee->resume,"output_linkedin"=>$output_linkedin, "output_name"=>$employee->name, "output_role"=>$employee->role);
        echo json_encode($data);

    }
}
```

Comment: you cant put how define `route`??

Comment: Certainly, added it ;)

Comment: if you use Request need change  `get` to `post` and put all on in your `form`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? I want to use 'get' since I'm only getting data from the database, and there is no form: the user clicks a picture and is shown additional info using the Ajax request.

Comment: @AlexanderVillalobos you can use `Request` in both `post` and `get `method.you are wrong here.

Comment: @MichielvanNesselrooij have you tried returning $request->all(); ?

Comment: It just returns {"query_string":null}

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a get data employeeId you have to pass a slug through your route either you should pass the data by POST method.

```
Route::get('/employeeInfo/{slug}', 'EmployeeController@getInfo');
```

And Get the slug on your function on controller .

```
public function getInfo($employeeId)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I suppose it could work, but it would require an unnecessary POST, would deviate from normal Ajax procedure, and most of all the above should work (it actually does work on my local machine!), so there's just something going wrong on the server...